# How to update data inside proxy object

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am working on lighting components newly. I have array of object, which I have assed to @track decorator of LWC variable.

I wanted to dynamically update the this assed variable, how to do it? I am getting error. Or is there any way to do it?

```
@track assetsFilters = [
    { name: 'drilling', checked: false },
    { name: 'offshore', checked: false },
    { name: 'others', checked: false }
];
```

I tried out and updating the data using JSON parse & JSON stringfy.

```
[{"name":"drilling","checked":false},{"name":"offshore","checked":false},{"name":"others","checked":false}];
```

What is best way to re-assign values to proxy object. Whether directly assign them or other way method, like react uses setState method to update values.

Ex
Directly assign

```
this.assetsFilters = [{"name":"drilling","checked":false},{"name":"offshore","checked":false},{"name":"others","checked":false}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify this variable normally, no need to do anything fancy:

```
this.assetsFilters[2].checked = false;
```

Do note that the variable must part of the class, so you must use `this` to access it.

```
export default class ... {
  @track assetsFilters = [
    { name: 'drilling', checked: false },
    { name: 'offshore', checked: false },
    { name: 'others', checked: false }
  ];
```

However, if the data comes from a cacheable data source (via wire), you need to duplicate the data first:

```
this.assetsFilters = this.assetsFilters.map(filter => ({...filter}));
```

Direct assignment also works, as in your example and the example immediately above.

This will give you a writable version of the data to work with.